# Subscribe to row changes in a database and push if ther is any changes to client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, system.reactive, sqldependency, subscribe

I am building online auction application in asp.net mvc using EF code first, currently I am updating the latest bid amount polling via ajax every 5 seconds. is there any other way I can achieve the same

For example subscribing to a datarow  which updates the UI element for any latest bid amount. 
example:

```
Bid bid = _bidService.GetLatestBid(auctionId)
bid.Subscribe();    
uielement.Update(bid.amount),
```

can I use SQLDependency and may be dotnet reactive extensions? any body has any sample code or solution?

Answer (score 2):

Enable [sql dependency](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashishme/archive/2008/08/28/enabling-sql-dependency-in-sql-server-database.aspx) on your database first.

Next, create [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) from SqlCommand and convert events into observable using [Observable.FromEventPattern](http://www.introtorx.com/uat/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#FromEvent).

sample code:

```
public class SqlDependencyObservable : ObservableBase<SqlNotificationEventArgs>
{
    private readonly SqlCommand _command;
    public SqlDependencyObservable(SqlCommand command)
    {
        _command = command;
    }

    protected override IDisposable SubscribeCore(IObserver<SqlNotificationEventArgs> observer)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(_command);

        return Observable.FromEventPattern<OnChangeEventHandler, SqlNotificationEventArgs>
            (addHandler: handler => dependency.OnChange += handler, removeHandler: handler => dependency.OnChange -= handler)
            .Select(i => i.EventArgs)
            .Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```